# How long does chilled breast milk last after taking from the refrigerator?

Tags: breastfeeding

I took a bottle of breast milk out of the refrigerator and forgot about it. At room temperature, how long is it good for? Can I put it back in the fridge?

Comment: Hi Jenny, and welcome! If the duplicate doesn't answer your question, please ask a new question explaining the difficulty you're still having. Thanks, and again, welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you shouldn't recool breast milk ever. However, room temperature is about 5-6 hours (only a little longer than adult food), so I would wager no more than that, less if it was in the fridge for awhile. The CDC has a handy chart we used:http://www.cdc.gov/breastfeeding/recommendations/handling_breastmilk.htm.

I know it sticks having to throw out hard work, but just remember there's always more where that came from!